# Changing default settings in xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

I am trying to change the default settings, such as the font of the axes' labels, in xmgrace.

I found many equivalent suggestions to do so online, for example the one in [this blog](http://blog.louic.nl/?p=249):

> open xmgrace, make the desired settings, save them as:
>
> ```
> ~/.grace/templates/Default.agr
> ```

But if I try to do this, I get the following error message:

```
Can't write to file ~/.grace/templates/Default.agr, check permissions!
```

The same happens if I open xmgrace with `sudo xmgrace`.

What should I do?

PS Since there was no `.grace/templates` folder in my home dir, I had to create it, like it is suggested [here](https://lists.phy.duke.edu/pipermail/phy246/2006/000125.html).

Comment: Did you try doing a `chmod` on the ~/.grace folder to allow you to modify it?

Comment: @feedMe What command should I use exactly? PS I forgot to specify it at first (now I've edited my answer), but the folder was created by me because there was no .grace folder in y home dir.

Comment: You could try `chmod 700 ~/.grace`. You aren't using a mounted remote drive by any chance are you? I had a similar problem once where xmgrace was trying to modify the wrong default folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have problems with folder ownership in the home directory, which you can check with `ls -la`.

This is how you can create your folder for default Grace/xmgrace templates and set the correct permissions. On the terminal:

```
cd ~
```

Need to use sudo to create a folder in root directory:

```
sudo mkdir .grace
```

When you create a folder with sudo it belongs to root. We change ownership with `chown` so that we can edit it without using sudo each time (this would also mean that xmgrace could potentially edit/overwrite the Default.agr file too, if we wanted):

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> .grace
# e.g. sudo chown -R valerio:valerio .grace
```

Now that we are able to make changes to the folder we go in and create a sub-directory called "templates":

```
cd .grace
mkdir templates
```

Now launch xmgrace, make changes to the new project and save the project anywhere (e.g. in the home directory) as "Default.agr".

Now move it to the templates folder:

```
mv /home/valerio/Default.agr ~.grace/templates/
```

So now when you launch xmgrace it should use this default template :)
The last step could be skipped if we save Default.agr directly to our templates folder, but xmgrace in normal mode cannot see hidden folders.